# Rep on profiles is misaligned according to whether a location is displayed

Tags: bug, profile-page

I've noticed this bug recently with the way user profiles are displayed on the list of all users:

[image]

The user's rep and badges show up beneath their location if there *is* a location. But when there isn't, the gap left by its absence is at the bottom instead of the top. Wouldn't it make much more sense to have the gap in the same position as the thing whose absence leaves the gap, like this:

[image: fixed!]

Comment: I actually thing it'd make more sense to list the country below the rep/badge stats, since it's optional data.

Comment: @CreationEdge Well, that would also be a valid fix. Anything but the inconsistency we have currently!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think the current version looks nicer than your proposed "fix".

Answer (score -1):

## No.

It's a design choice, and as you can see, it is designed like this:

- The area to the right of the avatar is for the following user-related information: name, location, rep, and badges
- The area to the right of, but below the avatar is for the tags.

If the first set of information doesn't vertically fill the box to the right of the avatar, then there's a gap.

I see no particular reason that your preferred design choice is superior, or "makes more sense".   Personally, I like it the way it is.

But in short:

## You're overthinking.